# Special RESTful routes

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, restful-url, conventions

I've always been confused with RESTful routes naming conventions when it comes to very specific behaviors.

Say I have an application with a frontend app and an API and I want the administrators to be able to disable accounts (or banning them for a few days). What should be the route for it? Should I just PUT to `/user/{id}` with as body the following object:

```
{
    // Other user parameters

    "enabled": false
}
```

Or should I have a specific route with a verb in it such as `/user/{id}/disable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edits should go to the same target URI as the GET that sees the changes.

So if your administrators are using

```
GET /user/12345
```

To read the enabled field, then they should be using one of

```
PUT /user/12345
POST /user/12345
PATCH /user/12345
```

to change it.

The motivation here is caching, and in particular [HTTP cache-invalidation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4).

---

> I've always been confused with RESTful routes naming conventions when it comes to very specific behaviors.

The trick is to recognize that we don't use names for behaviors, we use them for resources, which we recognize as a generalization of *documents*.  If we want to send information to a server, we do so by editing the representation of one of the documents hosted on that server.

> You have to learn how to narrow HTTP into a domain application protocol.... -- [Jim Webber 2011](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQVSzMV8DWc&t=3m08s)

Comment: That was very clear thank you! But say now, an action on the UI must change two entities of various types (and say that in no scenario should entity of type B change without a change on entity of type A). Should my frontend call both PUT routes or can the PUT route for A change my entity of type B? I’m worried my frontend starts getting too much business logic if I call both routes. And by the way, can all scenario be mapped to basic entity changes? Or are there special scenarios that require special routes?